# How do i set the property of one model to the property of another model using a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

I am having trouble passing a property value from one model to another,

I have a property referenced in the OrderTotalsModel here:

```
public string OrderTotal { get; set; }
```

I need that to show in the popUpOrderSummary View which uses the ShoppingCartModel,

I have created a property in this model:

```
public string popUpOrderTotal { get; set; }
```

I am aware that i need to pass the value of this property from the OrderTotalsModel to the ShoppingCartModel by using the ShoppingCartController,

I have so far added this code below the PrepareShoppingCartModel method:

```
model.popUpOrderTotal =
```

I have tried:

```
model.popUpOrderTotal = OrderTotalsModel.OrderTotal;
```

Comment: Where are you creating an instance of the OrderTotalsModel? It looks like you are attempting to assign the value of a property without creating an instance of the Model itself

Comment: Do you know about objects ?

Comment: @ChrisBint the OrderTotalsModel method is further down the controller im trying to add code there now

Comment: @Corbo152 you need an instance of the 'other' model in order to assign a property of it. The code above looks like you are not using the instance.

Comment: @ChrisBint i have looked through the controller have found the instance of the OrderTotalsModel. ( var model = new OrderTotalsModel(); ) however when under this instance its now referencing that model so i cannot retrieve a value from the other model :/

Comment: Could you post more of your code? It's very unclear what models you're talking about.

Comment: @admanb no problem ill create a gist with the 2 models the view and the controller

Comment: maybe its too late.. (this is odd), but can't you publish an event from OrderTotalsModel whenever OrderTotal changes. May be this is an overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use the same value in 2 models, you need to retrieve it from the same place.

If you are setting the value for `OrderTotal` in your controller, set it in the same way for the `ShoppingCartModel` e.g. by retrieving it from the database or calculating it.

If the value is set or updated in a view, this value needs to be posted back to an action where you can either save it for later use, or use it immediately to display another view such as your shopping cart.